# Why the command line utility takes very huge time to give output when invoke using java program?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, process, processbuilder

I am using libdmtx which comes with a command line utility which reads the image files for ECC200 Data Matrix barcodes, reads their contents, and writes the decoded messages to standard output. I have used command line utility in my java program on linux platform. I am using ubuntu linux. I have installed the libdmtx on my linux machine. and when I invoke the command

dmtxread -n /home/admin/ab.tif

on linux terminal it gives the decoded value of barcode in image immediately i.e within 15 seconds.
but when I am going to invoke this same command for same file using my java program the program takes huge time i.e average 16 minutes for the same command and same file above.

Following is my java code which invokes the above command

```
 public class Test {
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     //Build command 
     List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
     commands.add("dmtxread");
     commands.add("-n");
     commands.add("/home/admin/ab.tif");
     System.out.println(commands);
     //Run macro on target
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
     pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
     Process process = pb.start();

     //Read output
     StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
     String line = null, previous = null;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(line);
     }

     //Check result
     if (process.waitFor() == 0)
         System.out.println("Success!");
     System.exit(0);

     //Abnormal termination: Log command parameters and output and throw             ExecutionException
     System.err.println(commands);
     System.err.println(out.toString());
     System.exit(1);
 }
 }
```

I want to ask the experts that

Please can anyone explain me why java program takes such big time to invoke a simple command which will be get invoked withing 15 seconds if that command is directly run on command prompt.

Please can anyone tell me the solution to reduce this time.

I guess the program is taking this so much time because of JVMs internal thread which is invoking the process. Is my guess is right? If yes then how could I overcome to this problem.

Please guide me to solve this problem. Thanks You!